# Android libraries and GPS Tracker suggestions

Tags: android, gps, location, snapchat

I want to make a Android Application similar to Maps on Snapchat where you can see all your friends in the Map and can track their location, also I need a cheap GPS tracker devices, can you guys suggest any Android libraries so I don't have to code from scratch and an easy GPS tracker device to work with, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't your own smartphone include a GPS?

2) Android has a Listener included called LocationListener that is just what you want. You can find the docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

How to do this:
First create a LocationManager. Then a LocationListener and add the listener to the manager.
A method that could be good to use is:

> LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)

Which can be found in the documentation of LocationManager.

Comment: 1.) Yes, but I need a GPS tracker device in a case where Android Phones are not allowed in a establishment.
2.) Ok, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sorry can't help you with that. Got no experience of GPS's except for the phones.